# Excel - Auto fill drop-down menu

Tags: microsoft-excel

I do some voluntary work which involves me doing a shift and dispatching volunteers to emergency situations.  Each shift I create an excel spreadsheet of volunteers who are available for me to call out during that shift (I pass this sheet on to the person taking over from me so it needs to be accurate and neat).

So, I have sheet 1 which contains all their details and other required information such as 'area covered' 'mobile number' registration number etc etc.  I copy and paste this from an online master sheet.

What I would like to do is complete sheet 2 (template) where I can pick their names out of a drop down list which will then auto complete the following columns based on the information based in sheet 1.  There are over 400 names and I think this is the quickest and most accurate way of producing this shift sheet. I need to know that the mobile numbers are accurate and mistake-free and I think maintaining the original sheet is the best way to do this.

There is an added difficulty is that the contacts may change from one of my shifts to another, i.e. new volunteers may be added. It may be that the content doesn't change but without checking every name/number etc., I wouldn't know for sure so it makes sense just to copy the contacts from the online master sheet each time. The easy bit is that I can copy and paste the contacts in to Sheet 1 each time so I know it's the most up-to-date information.

**So, is there a way I can be in say, cell C13 on sheet 2, select a name from the drop-down list pointing to sheet one which will then complete the other columns from that row for me?**

For the last year I have been copying and pasting all the info between sheets for each person, but on some shifts I may have 40+ volunteers to add into sheet 2 and it takes an absolute age to just get the blessed sheet ready.....before I've even started the shift!

I have tried to work through the help on excel, but lots of it is written in a language I don't yet understand.

I fully appreciate this is a long shot, but if anyone can help, I would truly appreciate your advice and guidance.

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. according to public available data, I can see, that you did not read the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) I strongly recommend doing so, because it hat useful information in it.

Answer (score -1):

Visit this link, I think you will got your result.
[https://www.excel-university.com/select-drop-down-item-vlookup-return-multiple-attributes/[1](https://www.excel-university.com/select-drop-down-item-vlookup-return-multiple-attributes/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.